# Getting stuck in a read loop for an external file python

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop

```
def main():
    getLargest()



def getLargest():
    global line, value, highVal, numberFile
    numberFile = open('numbers.dat', 'r') 
    print("Lets find the largest number!")
    highVal = 0
    line = numberFile.readline()

    while line != "":
        value = int(line)
        if value >= highVal:
           highVal = value

    numberFile.close()   
    print("Highest value: ", highVal)


main()
```

out out is an endless loop.  I have a file with 25 randomly generated numbers it reads
from but the file just loops. Where did I go wrong?

This is for a class but I am just looking for why it loops and not the answer to my homework.

Comment: Hint: `line = numberFile.readline()` is called only once. You should put that line also into the `while` loop.

Comment: #here is where i put it:
    while line != "":
        line = numberFile.readline()
        value = int(line)
        if value >= highVal:
           highVal = value

#and i get 
line 21, in getLargest
    value = int(line)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through every line in the file you need to update the line variable every time the loop runs.
So you should change the loop to this: (While still keeping the `line = numberFile.readline()`!)

```
    while line != "":
        value = int(line)
        if value >= highVal:
           highVal = value
        line = numberFile.readline()
```

Otherwise the loop will check the same line. Again and again and again...